# Having problems analyzing a .dmp with WinDBG

Tags: .net, asp.net, memory, memory-leaks, windbg

I will start by saying this is the first time I have done anything with WinDbg so excuse my silly mistakes if that is the issue. My website has been using a lot of memory and after reading blogs and watching videos by Tess Fernandez I am trying to use WinDBG to analyze my dump file.

The setup: My web server is a Windows 2008 64bit machine running my asp.net 2.0 website in 32 bit compatablity mode. I have set an environment variable to get all the symbols so I don't get errors when I load WinDbg

I am using the following commands in WinDbg:

```
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\sos.dll
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
!eeheap -gc
```

and getting the following error:

> The garbage collector data structures
>   are not in a valid state for
>   traversal. It is either in the "plan
>   phase," where objects are being moved
>   around, or we are at the
>   initialization or shutdown of the gc
>   heap. Commands related to  displaying,
>   finding or traversing objects as well
>   as gc heap segments may not  work
>   properly. !dumpheap and !verifyheap
>   may incorrectly complain of heap 
>   consistency errors. Number of GC
>   Heaps: 1 Error requesting details

I have read this can be caused by some version mismatch and I think that could be the issue. In order to get this far, I have had to create the path

> C:\Windows\Symbols\mscordacwks_AMD64_x86_2.0.50727.4016.dll\49CC5B00590000\mscordacwks_AMD64_x86_2.0.50727.4016.dll

so the libraries are loaded when I call !eeheap -gc (otherwise some other errors come out). The problem is that I have taken this mscordacwks.dll from the normal .NET folder and not the Framework64 one. I don't know if this is the cause of the issue but I have been banging my head against a brick wall and don't really know what else to do so I would appreciate some help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670725/mscordacwks-dll-and-mscorwks-dll-confusions) post.  Also, make sure you're using the debugger and sos with the same bitness as the dump.  The [linked blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2009/02/18/failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005-or-what-is-mscordacwks-dll.aspx) in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670725/mscordacwks-dll-and-mscorwks-dll-confusions) explains this.  So in your case, use the 64bit windbg, load the sos.dll from Framework64, and make sure your mscordacwks is "mscordacwks_amd64_amd64_2.0.50727.4016.dll" and is in a path that is accessible.  I like to copy this assembly and the matching sos.dll into it's own folder together, but YMMV.

Comment: I think that answers what I need to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your system like John Robbins explains in his great post: https://www.wintellect.com/automatically-load-the-right-sos-for-the-minidump/

Then execute an `!analyze -v` first.

Comment: the link is dead now

Comment: link is now fixed